# Why use alphanumeric sessionids instead of numeric?

Tags: security, math, sessionid

I have 16 bytes in the packet structure to send a sessionID.
At the moment the allowed characters in the sessionID are `ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz1234567890`  (62 characters)
So there are `47672402000000000000000000000` combinations that are 16 characters long (62 ^ 16)

And there are `48453916000000000000000000000` combinations that are up to and including 16 characters long.

However 16 bytes (128 bits) can store up to the number `340282366920938463463374607431768211455` which is significantly more possibilities than the alphanumeric options.

Why do people use alphanumeric strings as sessionIDs instead of just a number?